# FileNotFound Error in AWS SageMaker while using sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to import linear learner algorithm container, and my code doesn't work

```
from sagemaker import image_uris
container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("linear-learner", region=boto3.Session().region_name, version="latest")
```

and this is the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-1a4aad999c94> in <module>
     10 
     11 from sagemaker import image_uris
---> 12 container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("linear-learner", region=boto3.Session().region_name, version="latest")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/utilities.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uris.py in retrieve(framework, region, version, py_version, instance_type, accelerator_type, image_scope, container_version, distribution, base_framework_version, training_compiler_config, model_id, model_version, tolerate_vulnerable_model, tolerate_deprecated_model, sdk_version, inference_tool, serverless_inference_config)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uris.py in _config_for_framework_and_scope(framework, image_scope, accelerator_type)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uris.py in config_for_framework(framework)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uri_config/linear-learner.json'
```

I tried with other algorithms, but it doesn't work at all. What should I fix in this code?

I need to get the training container of sagemaker built-in algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

from sagemaker import image_uris

container = image_uris.retrieve(region=boto3.Session().region_name, framework="linear-learner")

As indicated in this example:

https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/linear_learner_mnist/linear_learner_mnist.html

You can also try the above example from start to finish.